# Checking all inputs after un-checking them all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having problems creating a checkbox which is able to check and uncheck all other checkboxes.

The checkbox is able to uncheck all inputs but is unable to do the same in reverse.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vj6wY/1964/

**html:**

```
<div class='checkboxes'>
    All <input name="filterAll" type="checkbox"  checked="checked"  />
    Amazon <input name="filterAmazon" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    Abebooks <input name="filterAbebooks" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    Biblio <input name="filterBiblio" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    eBay <input name="filterEbay" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />        
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('input').on("change",function(){
            var filter_id = $(this).attr("name");  

            if($(this).is(':checked')){         
                switch(filter_id){
                    case "filterAll":
                    $("input").attr({checked: true});
                    break;
                }
            }

            else{               
                switch(filter_id){
                    case "filterAll":   
                    $("input").attr({checked: false});
                    break;                  
                }
            }
        });
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Vj6wY/1965/

You should now use `.prop('checked', true);` instead of `.attr()`

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('input').on("change",function(){
            var filter_id = $(this).attr("name");  

            if($(this).is(':checked')){     
                            alert("asdas");

                switch(filter_id){
                    case "filterAll":
                    $("input").prop('checked', true);
                    break;
                }
            }

            else{               
                switch(filter_id){
                    case "filterAll":   
                    $("input").prop('checked', false);
                    break;                  
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input#filterAll').change(function()
{
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vj6wY/1968/

Your amount of javascript can be drastically reduced. Note that I've added an Id to the select all checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('input').on("change",function(){
            var filter_id = $(this).attr("name");  

            if($(this).is(':checked')){         
                switch(filter_id){
                    case "filterAll":
                    $("input").attr('checked' , 'checked'});
                    break;
                }
            }

            else{               
                switch(filter_id){
                    case "filterAll":   
                    $("input").removeArrt('checked');
                    break;                  
                }
            }
        });
})
```